# iOS - How to reinitialize tableview cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I setup a `UITableViewController` in my app, but the data changes about 5 seconds after the initial layout.

How can I reinitialize the tableview once the data is loaded?

Essentially, I need the table view to be stripped down and start over. It's necessary that the following function is looped over again:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I suspect it's something really easy that I'm just not seeing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `reloadData` on your tableview.  In your `UITableViewController` instance or subclass just call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

call:

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

This function will recall all the datasource function of that table view

Answer (score 1):

Easy, in your UITableViewController just call reloaddata on the tableview.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If your using a CoreData database as your data source, you can also setup NSFetchedResultsController, it will observe the context and update the table automatically when a change occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This will reload the data you are using to populate you table cells:

```
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```